# Inline SVG <title> <desc> correct usage for accessilibility

Tags: html, svg, tags, accessibility

I am using a lot of inline svgs in my html and am a little confused about the best way to present them concerning accessibility.

I've see two methods to add `<title>` and `<desc>` to svgs -

```
<svg role="img" aria-label="[title + description]">
 <title>title text here</title>
 <desc>a description of the image here</desc>
 <path> etc.
</svg>

<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="my_svg_title my_svg_description">
 <title id="my_svg_title">title text here</title>
 <desc id="my_svg_description">a description of the image here</desc>
 <path> etc.
</svg>
```

The first method seems the best as I don't have to give unique IDs to each title and description (I have multiple svgs per page)? Is that the case? Is there anything else to take into consideration when choosing "aria-label" or "aria-labelledby"?

Also I am still confused a little about the role < desc > plays - is it exactly the same as alt? I always remove the xmlns and xmlns:xlink tags from inline svgs for optimisation, will google image search still reference these inline svgs as images? Will `<desc>` help with that?

If the inline svg will always display (do inline svgs ever not render?) then the `<desc>` will never be useful for missing images, which then only leaves page readers for accessibility which could use it. Do they?

Basically is it worth using/including `<desc>`?

Comment: Questions about SEO are off topic here and will get your question closed. I suggest you quickly remove any references to that and rewrite your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: SEO opinion is not allowed, but SEO as a topic is not banned, I.E. if it is a factual question (there is an `SEO` tag), overall the question is fine but good to give him a heads up to be careful.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie From the SEO Tag. GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Comment: Yes and so his question was 'how to present them for SEO' - it is a programming question (loosely, a `markup` question) and 'will google image search still reference these inline SVGs as images' is a valid question also as that is about a decision on whether to inline SVGs or put them in an external file. Which bit do you feel is outside of scope?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie The only part I want to be careful is "SEO as a topic is not banned". That's a really gray area and he's walking a fine line here.

Comment: thanks, that clear it up for me too. Cheers Rob and John!

Comment: Oh sry I phrased question badly... I was more concerned about how to implement it in HTML and what the title and desc meant in practical terms than than the SEO itself.

Comment: I took the SEO parts out, since accessibility is on-topic. If you still need an SEO answer, you can always ask that part on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of `<title>` like `alt`, think of `<description>` like `<figcaption>`

Your `<title>` should describe the image sufficiently to provide a user with an understanding of what the image contains.

If it is a complex image, or the image plays a vital role in an article that necessitates more details then use `<description>`.

[Deque did a great test of different methods](https://www.deque.com/blog/creating-accessible-svgs/) and found that your second version was the most reliable with a `title` and `description` linked via `aria-labelledby` and IDs, **so use that**.

Yes google will still reference them as images without `xmlns` served inline (provided you serve your page as mime type `text/html` otherwise you will get rendering issues). For external images I would leave it in, it is such a minor optimisation it isn't worth it.

Inline SVGs do not get indexed as far as I am aware in Google Image Search (but their content still contributes to your SEO in Google Search Algorithms slightly so it is still worth having `<description>` where appropriate.)

SVGs will always render if inline ([assuming the browser supports SVG](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) which is very likely).

Yes include `<desc>` if the image is sufficiently complex that you can't describe it with `<title>` in 20 words or less (general rule).

**final thought** - `alt` tags, `titles` etc. are all about accessibility, don't worry about them for SEO keywords as you will end up damaging usability. I know you didn't mention that but I thought I would put it in here for clarity.

**p.s.** - Next time, maybe limit this to 1 or 2 questions at once as that was a lot to answer!

Comment: Thanks a million for taking the time. Great answer. The info about aria-labelledby is very useful as I would have probably used the other method.

From everything you have said it seems like using title will be enough for my purposes... I was having trouble understanding exactly what different roles this text would perform compared to more traditional title and alt.

I am more concerned about accessibility really than SEO, should have put into post title but thought would make it too long. Thanks again!!