# Svg inside h1 tag

Tags: svg, accessibility, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project, where where I would like to use an svg as my main heading.

```
import Header from "../images/header.svg"

return (
  <h1>
      <Header/>
  </h1>
)
```

Thers is no text in the svg (the text is made purely using rects and paths), so what do I do in terms of accessibility and SEO optimization?

Comment: removed the SEO tag for you, people blindly close things with that tag, will drop you an answer now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two ways to address this, visually hidden text or by adding a `<title>` to your SVG.

Do not use `aria-label` as [support is not great](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/) (you will see people recommending that for SVGs, `aria-label` does not tend to work well on static / non-interactive elements).

### Visually Hidden text (screen reader only text)

Visually hidden text is not visible on the screen but will still be read by a screen reader.

Please use the CSS class below to visually hide text, it has better compatibility and is future proofed compared to most current "screen reader only" classes [as explained in this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894)

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Welcome To Our Site</span>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
        <path fill="#666" d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z">
        </path>
    </svg>
</h1>
```

**important:** notice how I add `focusable="false"` as well as `aria-hidden="true"` to the SVG, this is to fix a bug with Internet Explorer where SVGs are focusable and to hide the SVG from screen readers. I used a youtube icon to represent your text as that was the closest SVG I had to hand!

### Add a `<title>` element to your SVG.

The `<title>` element is effectively the same as `alt` on a normal image. Using this gives the screen reader something to announce.

Obviously you would then remove the `aria-hidden="true"` from it so it can be read by a screen reader!

### Update after comments to include best practices for `<title>` and or `<desc>`

Thanks to the comments I realised this answer was lacking some key information on how to correctly use a `<title>`.

[In this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563793/2702894) I referenced [a series of tests by deque](https://www.deque.com/blog/creating-accessible-svgs/) which show that the most reliable method for labelling an SVG for screen readers using `WAI-ARIA` was to use `aria-labelledby` and point that to the `<title>` (and `<desc>` if you have both).

So a rough idea of how to do this is as follows:

```html
<h1>
    <svg aria-labelledby="welcome-title" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
        <title id="welcome-title">Welcome To Our Site</title>
        <path fill="#666" d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z">
         </path>
    </svg>
</h1>
```

### Which is better?

Go for visually hidden text.

It works all the way back to IE6 which predates SVG!

It also works in a text only browser (one that does not understand CSS) as it will still be displayed. It is an edge case but still a win for visually hidden text!

Comment: No problem, I have just updated it to tidy things up - just take note of the **important:** section for guidance as I only just added that. Glad it helped!

Comment: desc should be roughly the equivalent of alt on a normal image.

Comment: `alt` is for providing a brief description of an image, which is exactly what a `<title>` is for in a SVG. `<desc>` is for providing more detailed information like a `<figcaption>`. [I answered about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563793/2702894), and here is a [reference on sitepoint that confirms](https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/) and [a reference in the new code.](http://thenewcode.com/1026/Making-SVG-Accessible).

Comment: @RobertLongson [You have mentioned this before as a comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208144/why-does-a-link-not-take-the-title-of-a-contained-svg-as-its-accessible-nam#comment111772807_63208144) but didn't respond to me then. Can you explain why `<desc>` is more appropriate than `<title>` please as I do not want to be providing the wrong information to people in my answers, I can only go off what I have read and my interpretation of the W3C guidance. Would love to see an official source on something if you have that so I can quote it in my answers.

Comment: These days [aria-describedby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/desc) is actually recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but then we have the same issue (which one should you use) as [aria-labelledby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title) is recommended with the `<title>` attribute, which would still lead me to think `<title>` is more applicable as an alternative to `<alt>`. Also [deque did a great study on compatibility](https://www.deque.com/blog/creating-accessible-svgs/) and `title` and `description` linked via `aria-labelledby` and IDs was the most robust so [that is the recommended practice as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563793/2702894)

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the important information I did not include when it comes to `<title>` best practices, thanks @RobertLongson. I would still love to see why I would use `<desc>` and not `<title>` for the equivalent of an `alt` attribute if you have time to explain.